# How to focus on a secondary window?

Tags: uwp

I have an app that has two secondary windows.  I have buttons that let you switch between windows, which works fine:

`ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync(_viewToSwitchToId);`

When the user launches our app via the jumplist (under the recent heading when you right click on the app icon in the taskbar), I would like to be able to choose which secondary window to focus on.

I use the same code as above, but it does not work (the same secondary window is automatically chosen regardless of what `_viewToSwitchToId` I provide).

I'm guessing there's some difference between calling the `SwitchAsync()` from when my app already has focus (from my button) and when it does not have focus (jumplist).

Any ideas?

---

**Edit**

[Git repository](https://github.com/fman028/FocusOnSecondaryWindowIssue) with repro of `SwitchAsync()` issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to be able to choose which secondary window to focus on

I added the  `SwitchAsync()` method to `OnLaunched` for a testing, and when launch the app from the jump list, the application view will switch to the assigned view correctly. For example:

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
    int newViewId = 0;
    await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        Frame frame = new Frame();
        Window.Current.Content = frame;
        Window.Current.Activate();           
        newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
    });
    await ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync(newViewId);
    //bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
}
```

If you still have issues please provide a minimal reproduced project for a testing on our side.

Updated:
[`SwitchAsync(Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewswitcher#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ApplicationViewSwitcher_SwitchAsync_System_Int32_System_Int32_) method can work well for your scenario. For example:

```
// Create 2 secondary views
CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
int newViewId = 0;
await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    frame.Navigate(typeof(page1));
    Window.Current.Content = frame;
    Window.Current.Activate();
    ApplicationView appView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
    newViewId = appView.Id;
    appView.Title = newViewId.ToString();
    _viewIds.Add(newViewId);
});

bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);

CoreApplicationView newView2 = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
int newViewId2 = 0;
await newView2.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    frame.Navigate(typeof(page2));
    Window.Current.Content = frame;
    Window.Current.Activate();
    ApplicationView appView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
    newViewId2 = appView.Id;
    appView.Title = newViewId2.ToString();
    _viewIds.Add(newViewId2);
});

bool viewShown2 = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId2);

// Switch to first secondary view, BUT focuses on last secondary view :/
Debug.WriteLine("Switching to secondary view with id: " + _viewIds[0]);
// bool viewShowntoone = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(_viewIds[0]);
await ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync(_viewIds[0], _viewIds[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response Sunteen!  Did you test with 2 secondary windows?  It works fine as long as there is only one secondary window, but as soon as there are more the `SwitchAsync(viewId)` ignores the `viewId` parameter.  I've added a [git repo](https://github.com/fman028/FocusOnSecondaryWindowIssue) highlighting the issue.

Comment: Di you get a chance to try out the git repo?

Comment: @Felix. I tested. In your scenario you may need to assign from which view to another by  `SwitchAsync(Int32, Int32)` method. For code details please reference the updated reply.

Comment: Specifying the `fromViewId` works, as long as that `fromViewId` matches the last active view of my app.  Any idea on how to keep track of the last active view?  (The app could have lots of secondary windows :/ )

Comment: I think I will try use `Window.Activated` to track the last active window.  Thank you very much for all your help :)

Comment: Actually, `LaunchActivatedEventArgs.CurrentlyShownApplicationViewId` already gives me the exact view id I want :)